# Nginx config redirect www

Tags: nginx, subdomain, config, no-www

I'm having trouble figuring out my nginx config.

My config is supposed to force the use of https and no www. Some subdomains *api.domain.com*,  *api.staging.domain.com* is allowed. The last mentioned is currently configured in another conf file, not enclosed here.

Currently my problem is that this seems to allow www. I need www to be 301 redirected to no www. The subdomain www is setup as a cname in the dns config.

Can someone help me out?

```
server {
        listen          54.00.00.00;
        server_name     54.00.00.00;
        rewrite         .* https://domain.com$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
        listen          80;
        return          301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen          443 default ssl;
        server_name     domain.com api.domain.com;
        root            /var/www/domain.com/current/web;

        ##
        # Certificate Settings
        ##

        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that this `server`

```
server {
    listen          80;
    return          301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Matches all servers, even the ones with `www` mind that if you are requesting `http://www.example.com`, `$host` will be `www.example.com`, so you end up redirecting to the `https` version with `www`.

If you want to do a catch all and still strip `www` from those who have it I suggest it would be better to use regex in the server name

```
server {
    server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
    return 301 https://$domain$request_uri;
}
```